# Segmentation Fault 11 when implementing pointer based heap structure

Tags: c

I am trying to implement the heap data structure, but I am having trouble getting the following code to run.

I get a

```
line 1: 47794 Segmentation fault: 11
```

Error.

```
void heap_initialize(heap* p_heap){
  heap new_heap = {
    .size       = 0,
    .alloc_size = 1024,
    .root = NULL,
  };
  *p_heap = new_heap;
}

void heap_insert(heap* addr, void* p_thing, int priority) {
  heap my_heap = *addr;
  node* root   = my_heap.root;

  if (root == NULL) {
    my_heap.root = p_thing;
  }

  int i         = my_heap.size + 1;
  node new_node = {
    .thing    = p_thing,
    .priority = priority
  };

  node* new_node_addr = &new_node;

  node* child_addr = root + (i * 4);
  node child       = *new_node_addr;

  node* parent_addr = root + ((i / 2) * 4);
  node parent       = *parent_addr;

  while ( child.priority > parent.priority && root != &child ) {
    node* temp  = parent_addr;
    parent_addr = child_addr;
    child_addr  = temp;

    node child  = *child_addr;
    i           = i / 2;

    parent_addr = root + (i * 4);
    node parent = *parent_addr;
  }
```

Main

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

  heap* addr = malloc(1024);
  heap_initialize(addr);

  char element[3] = "12";

  heap_insert(addr, element, 10);




  return 0;
}
```

From what I have been able to read, segmentation errors occur when trying to access memory that you dont have access to, but I haven't been able to figure out why
Any idea as to why this occurs?

UPDATE
result from lldb debugger

```
Process 47876 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x82070f, 0x0000000100000e0f heap`heap_insert + 207, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000e0f heap`heap_insert + 207
heap`heap_insert + 207:
-> 0x100000e0f:  movq   (%rcx), %rdi
   0x100000e12:  movq   %rdi, -0x88(%rbp)
   0x100000e19:  movq   0x8(%rcx), %rcx
   0x100000e1d:  movq   %rcx, -0x80(%rbp)
```

Comment: Run in a debugger, it will stop at the location of the crash.

Comment: updated post, not sure how to interpret debugger result

Comment: `heap* addr = malloc(1024);` this is wrong, you should us the correct size, which will be `sizeof(heap) * count`, where `count` is the number of structs you want to allocate.

Comment: It will help if you build a *debug* version of your program. Add e.g. the `-g` flag when building. This will allow you to see file-names and actual line numbers of the location of the crash. Also check the function call-stack (use the command `bt`).

Comment: `if (root == NULL) { ... }` does not assign a value to `root`, and later `*parent_addr` tries to read from that `NULL` address.

Comment: Also, inside the loop you have this statement: `node parent = *parent_addr;`. It declares a *new* `parent` structure, one that's only life-time is to the next line where the loop ends. Are you sure you want to declare a new `parent` variable?

Comment: @DCoder I dont get it, I assign `my_heap.root = p_thing;` if `root == null`

Comment: @Tarlen: exactly, you assign to `my_heap.root`, not plain `root`.

Comment: @DCoder thanks that was the problem

Comment: That might be the immediate answer, but the comments @JoachimPileborg wrote still apply - please take the time to review them.

Comment: how are `heap` and `node` declared? why are you sure 1024 is the right size for heap?